# composer.lock timestamp format

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to track down the php setting that is causing diffs in my composer.lock file.

Some machines produces:

```
"time": "2017-01-06T14:33:56+00:00"
```

On another machine:

```
"time": "2017-01-06 14:33:56"
```

I commit the composer.lock file in git and these different time format is causing unnecessary diff.

Comment: Do the two machines have dramatically different PHP versions?

Comment: Or even _slightly_ different PHP versions? What about Composer versions?

Comment: Any ideas how to reproduce it? Can't generate it with atom format.

Comment: Just to clarify:  "2017-01-06 14:33:56" is the OLD way of doing it, "2017-01-06T14:33:56+00:00" is the new improved way that you should be aiming for.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Composer changed the internally created timestamp format with version 1.3.0 - if you experience different results, make sure you update all your Composer installations to the most recent version (which is 1.3.1 at the time of writing) by running

```
composer selfupdate
```

or maybe

```
sudo composer selfupdate
```

depending on how Composer is installed.

Comment: Do you have more information about this change? I can't find it referenced in the [changelog](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: The change was probably [64317e1ff8](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/64317e1ff86b1f3b0e7dd5eead5c4bbcc16e247b), but no further information there.